# Simple Coroutine Animation script breaks unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, while-loop, wait, coroutine

Alright, so I'm using a coroutine to wait 6 seconds before executing a method to change a float in an animator, really simple stuff. My issue is that something in this script is causing my unity editor to completely lock up when I place it on a gameobject, and I don't know why. I don't think I have any infinite loops going, but I'm not sure. Anyone have any ideas? thx ahead of time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class handanimatordock : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator hand;
    private float Blendfloat;
    bool ChangeHand = false;
    private float timefloat = 0.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waiter());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void changeHands()
    {

        if (ChangeHand == false)
        {
            ChangeHand = true;

            while (Blendfloat != 1.0f)
            {
                Blendfloat = Blendfloat + 0.01f;
                hand.SetFloat("Blend", Blendfloat);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            ChangeHand = false;

            while (Blendfloat != 0.0f)
            {
                Blendfloat = Blendfloat - 0.01f;
                hand.SetFloat("Blend", Blendfloat);
            }

        }

    }


    IEnumerator waiter()
    {
        

        //Wait for 4 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
        changeHands();
        StartCoroutine(waiter());
    }


}
```

Comment: When I get loops taking a long time, I print out the loop count to my console and then break manually if I get an infinite loop. I also test whether the various loops are entered, again, by printing to the console. What type of testing have you done so far to see where the problem may lie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an infinite loop in

```
while (Blendfloat != 1.0f)
{
    Blendfloat = Blendfloat + 0.01f;
    hand.SetFloat("Blend", Blendfloat);
}
```

**Never** directly compare two `float` values using `==` or `!=`.

Due to floating point impression a value like

```
10f * 0.1f
```

might end up being `1.000000001` or `0.99999999` though logically you would expect exactly `1`. So your condition is probably never false!

Usually you rather give it a certain range like e.g.

```
while(Mathf.Abs(Blendfloat - 1) > certainThreshold)
```

Unity has for that [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
while(!Mathf.Approximately(Blendfloat, 1f)
```

which basically equals comparing to a threshold of [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)

```
which(Math.Abs(Blendfloat - 1) > Mathf.Epsilon)
```

---

Note that anyway what you have right now will execute the entire loop in **one single frame**.

If you really wanted it to fade over time you need to do one iteration per frame in e.g. a Coroutine!